# Oracle to PostgreSQL: Create type object

Tags: postgresql, oracle

In Oracle:

```
create or replace type tr_del as object (row_id varchar2(18), pk_id number);

select tr_del(last_name, employee_id) 
from employees where 
department_id=30;
```

output:

```
(Raphaely, 114)  
(Khoo, 115)  
(Baida, 116)
```

How can I achieve the same in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the syntax is different, you can achieve exactly what you want.

You can create type by using the script below;

```
CREATE TYPE tr_del AS (row_id varchar(18), pk_id integer);
```

Then your table structure should look like this;

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
   department_id integer,
   any_field_name tr_del,
   ...
);
```

After that you can use it in the query like this;

```
SELECT
    (any_field_name).row_id AS last_name,
    (any_field_name).pk_id AS employee_id
FROM
    employees
WHERE
    department_id = 30;
```

[Fiddle is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3bb07/3/0)

You may want to read [Composite Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html) section.